# Make index reflect files at given paths in worktree, including their presence

Tags: git

I have a script which updates a repository, and adds / deletes files at some given paths. How can I commit these changes knowing the paths? I.e.,

- If a specified file is in the worktree, copy it to the index
- If a specified file is in the index but not in the worktree, remove it from the index
- If a specified file is neither in the worktree nor in the index, do nothing.

`git add` fails at the last corner case - if any of the paths on its command line doesn't exist, it exits with an error and does nothing.

I considered:

- `git add --ignore-errors`, unfortunately does not consider the file not existing as the kind of error it ignores.
- `git add --ignore-missing` frustratingly exists but only works with `--dry-run`.
- One `git add` invocation per path, ignoring errors, would work but is slow and does not allow discerning errors due to the file not existing (neither in index nor worktree) from other errors.
- One `git add --all` invocation does not allow staging only files at certain paths.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far is to construct a list of paths to pass to `git add` by inspecting the git index and worktree explicitly.

Given the repository:

```bsh
git init .
echo $RANDOM > ignore-edited
echo $RANDOM > ignore-deleted
echo $RANDOM > add-edited
echo $RANDOM > add-deleted
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'

echo $RANDOM > ignore-new
echo $RANDOM > ignore-edited
rm             ignore-deleted
echo $RANDOM > add-new
echo $RANDOM > add-edited
rm             add-deleted
```

and the list of files to update:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' add-new add-edited add-deleted add-nonexistent | sort \
    > /tmp/filelist.txt
```

We can construct the file list by getting the union between the intersection of our files to add and the index, and the intersection of our files to add and those existing in the worktree:

```bsh
comm -12 /tmp/filelist.txt <(git ls-files) \
    > /tmp/files-in-index.txt
while read -r line ; do test -e "$line" && printf -- '%s\n' "$line" ; done < /tmp/filelist.txt \
    > /tmp/files-in-worktree.txt
sort -um /tmp/files-in-index.txt /tmp/files-in-worktree.txt \
    > /tmp/files-to-add.txt
< /tmp/files-to-add.txt xargs git add
```

Or, in one invocation:

```bsh
sort -um \
    <(comm -12 /tmp/filelist.txt <(git ls-files)) \
    <(while read -r line ; do test -e "$line" && printf -- '%s\n' "$line" ; done < /tmp/filelist.txt) |
    xargs git add
```

Comment: In #git, osse suggested using `git status --porcelain -uall` to query the index and worktree, which would then require only calculating the intersection between its output and the file list, without an additional union operation.